# NIntegrate gives two different answers (errors) for the same integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

The integrand I want to integrate from u=183/985 to u=5 is:

```
integrand[u]=(1/u)*Sqrt[u^2-33489/970225]*BesselJ[1, 125*Sqrt[u^2-33489/970225]]*FAu[u^2])
```

where FAu is an interpolated function of a table of data (more info below). Here is a plot of the integrand from 183/985 to 5:
[image: Plot of the integrand]
If I integrate this function directly using NIntegrate

```
NIntegrate[integrand[u],{u,183/985, 5}, WorkingPrecision->10, AccuracyGoal->10]//AbsoluteTiming
```

I get:

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in u near {u} = {0.533503182102844852657037466919066363800523835958162522877040}. NIntegrate obtained -1.98098626595186890458305013843987581889411200403876177007049*10^-9 and 4.40473710561241740892192176221042197437404611846026487150173`60.*^-8 for the integral and error estimates.

{5.87632, -1.980986266*10^-9}

as my answer.

But, if I split the integral in 5: [183/985,1], [1,2], ..., [4,5] and add up the results like this:

```
Total[NIntegrate[I[u], {u, ##}, WorkingPrecision->10, AccuracyGoal->10]&@@@Partition[Flatten[{183/985,Range[1,5]}],2,1]]//AbsoluteTiming
```

1. it takes 100x more time to evaluate the integral (565.563s),
2. it gives no error,
3. it gives a different answer (-1.538*10^-11).

**Context**

To obtain the function FAu[u] I create a table from the integral

```
TAu[q_]:=(1/104.25919385918256`20)NIntegrate[If[q == 0 || r == 0, r^2/(1 + E^((r - 6.642`20.)/0.549`20.)), (Sin[q*r]/(q*r))*(r^2/(1 + E^((r - 6.642`20.)/0.549`20.)))], {r, 0, 100}, MinRecursion -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 15,PrecisionGoal -> 7, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
```

and then interpolate it

```
FAu=Interpolation[TAu];
```

**Questions**

As I have been using Mathematica for numerical calculations for not very long I have a few questions:

1. How can I be sure of the result NIntegrate returns? Since FAu[u] is evaluated using NIntegrate, it itself may contain errors. I've tried several NIntegrate methods and all of them return different results (except GaussKronrodRule, which I think NIntegrate automatically uses it for this case).
2. Why splitting the integral takes much longer to evaluate and why it returns a different answer?
3. I'm still confused with PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal options. If I want a result with at least 3 - 4 decimal digits after the period, this means I should be using AccuracyGoal->4 instead of PrecisionGoal?

Thanks

Comment: Copying and pasting your code in Mathematica does not produce valid expressions and some quantities are missing. (E.g. `q`, `TAu`.) Please, fix those. Also, you are using `WorkingPrecision` in a wrong way -- you probably want `PrecisionGoal`.

Comment: Recommend reading Mathematica's help on NIntegrate and oscillatory integrands, to include Levin's method.

Comment: Please upload code that actually runs, including code for generating plots.

Comment: I'd look into `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` in the doc center.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I'm very sorry for the mistyping, now it should be correct. In it's definition TAu is a function of 'q', which is then interpolated into FAu[q]. Then, in the integrand, FAu is a function of u^2.
I've seen in several places that WorkingPrecision need to be set for PrecisionGoal to work, i.e. WorkingPrecision->wp says that NIntegrate should work internally with precision wp, and returns the answer when PrecisionGoal is satisfied.

Comment: @MikeY Thanks for your suggestion. I had already given a try to LevinRule, but the oscillatory part (Kernel) should be the solution of an ODE. FAu (which is oscillatory) is obtained solving an integral, which could be rewritten as an ODE. But the Bessel function is also an oscillating function, so I would need an ODE for BesselJ[1,...]FAu[...], which I don't have.

Comment: Which one oscillates faster? I think it is the Bessel function, with the other term being orders of magnitude slower. You can tell the NIntegrate that that is the oscillating kernel and to ignore FAu, to help it out.

Comment: `I[u] = ...` gives an error. So does `FAu = Interpolation[TAu]`.  Please post working code.

Comment: I get no error, so you must be doing something different.  Please post your code.

Comment: The term 'I' is protected in Mma. Need to use something else.

Comment: @MikeY I wrote the code that way only for this post, I'll change the letter I to any other one. Thanks

Comment: Consider changing the variable of integration to `u^2`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems to work fine here. Note the simplification of `TAu`. The extra options on precision, accuracy, etc., essentially had no effect.

```
TAu[q_] := (1/104.25919385918256`20) NIntegrate[ (Sin[ q*r]/(q*r))*(r^2/(1 + E^((r - 6.642)/0.549))), {r, 0, 100}]

dat = Table[{u, TAu[u]}, {u, (183/985)^2, 5^2+.1, .1}];

FAu = Interpolation[dat];
```

Define `aa=33489/970225` to clean up the integrand.

```
integrand[u_] :=  (1/u) Sqrt[u^2 - aa] BesselJ[1, 125*Sqrt[u^2 - aa]] FAu[u^2];

NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, (183/985), 5}]

(*    -5.07583*10^-7    *)

 NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, (183/985), 1}] + 
 NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, 1, 2}] + 
 NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, 2, 3}] + 
 NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, 3, 4}] + 
 NIntegrate[integrand[u], {u, 4, 5}]

(*    -5.07583*10^-7    *)
```